# Runtime error in my code though its correct

Tags: c++, vector, runtime-error

This is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int findat(string x, vector<string> &str, int np)
{
    int loc;
    for(int i=0; i<np; i++) if(x == str[i]) loc = i;
    return loc;
}


int main()
{
    int np; cin>>np; 
    vector <int> v(5);
    fill(v.begin(), v.end(), 0);
    vector <string> str; string buff;
    for(int i=0; i<np; i++) cin>>buff; str.push_back(buff);
    //Took names
    int price, no, rem;
    for(int i=0; i<np; i++)
    {
        cin>>buff;
        cin>>price>>no;
        v[findat(buff,str,np)]+=price%no;
        for(int i=0; i<no; i++)
        {
            cin>>buff;
            v[findat(buff,str,np)]+= price/no;
        }
    }

    for(int i=0; i<np; i++)
    {
        cout<<str[i]<<" "<<v[i]<<endl;
    }
}
```

This is a USACO training gateway question which you can find at http://www.spoj.com/problems/GIFT1/

After I compile the program and run it, I get a runtime error showing that my IDE has stopped working. I wanted to know where I am going wrong about it and also if I can remove the findat() function in some way.

The findat() function finds the location of the gift giver from the array, i.e the index of the array. I then use the index to initialize the amounts of the other gift givers in the main() function. I am new to all this and so please also suggest me how I can efficiently remove some lines of code.

Thanks

Comment: Heres an optimization : break once you find the string you're looking for, no point in searching through the remaining strings in the vector once you find the one you're looking for

Comment: @Shreeyash - Try to keep the question single topic: are you trying to find out why your code crashes, or how you can reduce the complexity of the code? Pick one, please.

Comment: Pro-tip: if your code causes a runtime error, it is most likely **not** correct (even if the title says otherwise) ;-)

Comment: could you tell us the runtime error?

Comment: At a glance 1) The hardcoded number in `vector <int> v(5)` looks very suspicious. 2) `str` always contains exactly one element. 3) if `x` isn't found in `str`, `findat` returns an indeterminate value (and the program is undefined).

Answer (score 1):

One problem is here:

```
for(int i=0; i<np; i++) cin>>buff; str.push_back(buff);
```

That's the same as this:

```
for(int i=0; i<np; i++)
    cin>>buff;
str.push_back(buff);
```

What you want is this:

```
for(int i=0; i<np; i++) {
    cin>>buff;
    str.push_back(buff);
}
```